# Win32: Create a class with standard cursor (IDC_CROSS)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cursor

Win32 newbie here. I've been having some issues with using one of the standard WinAPI cursors: IDC_CROSS. When creating a new class, I set the class cursor to be IDC_CROSS, a crosshair. However, when I run the program my cursor never changes and is always the standard arrow.

```
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINSCREENCAP));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINSCREENCAP);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}
```

I'm using VC++ 2010 Express, and this happens even when I create a new (non-empty) Win32 project and change only the class cursor value. Is there something horribly obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: No, it is nothing obvious.  Try adding WM_SETCURSOR to the window procedure to see it it fires at all, maybe some program is hijacking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window class cursor is set correctly. You may want to check that the class registration succeeds (`RegisterClassEx` returns a non-zero value), and that the window is actually created based on this class registration. The main thing to watch out for is that the `CreateWindow` function is called with the same window class name and `HINSTANCE` value. You could also check that `LoadCursor` actually returns a non-zero value. If `LoadCursor` fails for some reason it returns zero and Windows will default to the standard cursor.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because the cursor was set correctly, and the problem (though I'm still not sure exactly what it was) seemed to be with my dev environment (VC++ Express on a virtual machine). The above code works fine in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment here in case it helps anyone - the cursor wasn't appearing correctly due to the environment from which I was accessing the VM. My RDP client was displaying only the cursor from my physical machine, and not the one specified by the VM.